# Simple Python TypeError using the sorted function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently learning python with the 3rd edition of python crash course. Trying to figure out why this happens when I try to use the sorted function.

```
cars = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota', 'subaru']
print(sorted(cars))
```

Trying to figure out why this happening. Running the code instead of getting the temporarily sorted list back I get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-6 in line 2
      1 cars = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota', 'subaru']
----> 2 print(sorted(cars))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: At some point in your code, you did the equivalent of `print = None` or `sorted = None`. You must have overwritten/shadowed a built-in name (either `print` or `sorted`) in order to get that error. So, without seeing a [mre] of your code, it's impossible to help you beyond this vague guess, but on the other hand, I can't imagine what else the issue could be.

Comment: My money is on `sorted = cars.sort()` or something along those lines.

Comment: Yup, you guys were right. Exactly what happened. Started a fresh file and reloaded VS and it worked fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is somewhere in your code, you shadowed the `print` or `sorted` keyword to None or some other value resulting in None being assigned to either of them. That's why this exception occurs. If you can share your compete code for better context, perhaps I can figure out what's wrong with the code. I you want to fix the issue yourself, debug the code and figure out where you did shadowing to keywords.